# intellij - creating schema and hibernate mapping from bean

Tags: hibernate, intellij-idea, mapping, schema

... if I have the following bean for instance (as an example from [here](http://www.tikalk.com/java/load-a-tree-with-jpa-and-hibernate)):

```
@Entity 
@Table(name = "tree") 
public class Node { 

    @Id 
    @GeneratedValue 
    private Integer id; 

    @NotNull 
    private String name; 

    @OneToMany 
    @JoinColumn(name = "parent_id") 
    @OrderColumn
    private List<Node> children = new LinkedList<Node>(); 

    ... 
}
```

Is it possible in IntelliJ 12.0 ultimate to create schema and hibernate mapping from the bean? I found lots of references on generating beans from existing schemas, but not the other way around.
Or am I asking for a bit much?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible yet, I've created a new [feature request](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-99713), please start/vote.